# Display only Even numbers in C#, using Windows Forms

Tags: c#

I think this is a very easy answer and I understand that you enter something like this get an even number:

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
```

But I am just struggling to figure out how to slot it into my current code that I have here...
I have a form like so:

I am double clicking the 'Show Numbers' button

[image]

And I want the user to click the show numbers button and it only spits out even numbers, regardless if the box is checked or not.

```
    namespace CHECK_BOXES
{
  
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        textBox1.Text = "";
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                textBox1.Text += i.ToString() + "\r\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 20; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                textBox1.Text += i.ToString() + "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: You need to review your C# textbook. It'll teach you how to use `if` statements.

Comment: What does "spits out" mean in C#?

Comment: What should the "Increasing order" checkbox do anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this function:

```
public bool IsEven(int value)
{
    return value % 2 == 0;
}
```

and then update your for each loop with the following statement:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    if (IsEven(i))
    {
        textBox1.Text += i.ToString() + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Or just easily increment `i` in for loop with 2.

Comment: No reason to have a routine for this, even if, make it a static function as no state is involved.

Comment: I agree, I just want to show how to use if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just do "double"-steps.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i += 2) { // <- pay attention, i will be incremented by 2
    textBox1.Text += i.ToString() + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Or another `i += 2`

Answer (score 0):

could be one line with Linq

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", Enumerable.Range(0, 20)
            .Where((_, index) => index % 2 == 0).Select(x => x));
```